# how to concatenate two images vertically in matlab?

Tags: matlab

```
>> a=imread ('Vasculature.tif');
>> b = imresize (a, [400,400]);
>> c=imread ('activation.tif');
>> d= imresize (c, [400,400]);
>> e=imadd (b,d);
```

the code I was able to work with was for horizontal concatenation pls do tell me concatenating the image vertically..

Comment: I guess that you can just transpose it, I mean b and d are just matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the images and make a matrix of them,
use for matrix a and matrix b,

```
c = vertcat(a,b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `cat`:

```
c = cat(1, a, b);
```

You can also use straight MATLAB matrix building:

```
c = [a; b];
```

This is assuming that the images have the **same number of columns**.  Doing `c = [a b]` concatenates matrices **column-wise**.  If you want to do it by row, use the **semi-colon**. Take a look at this basic tutorial on MATLAB operations here to get you started: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/basic-matrix-operations.html